цикл сохраняет только первое значение в файле excel
пишу программу для формирования сводного файла excel.
есть фрагмент кода
res = {}
for el in datas:
    if res.get(el[7]):
        res[el[7]].append(el)
    else:
        res[el[7]] = [el]

for key, values in res.items():
itogFileName = 'Сводный отчет.xlsx'
itogName = (split_text(reduce_name(key))[1]) # сокращенное наименование
itogLen = (len(values)) # Количество записей
    if not os.path.exists(itogFileName):
        itogWB = openpyxl.Workbook()
        itog_sheet = itogWB['Sheet']
        itog_sheet.title = itogSheetName
        itog_sheet['A1'] = 'Наименование отдела'
        itog_sheet['B1'] = FolderName

        for row in itog_sheet.iter_cols(min_row=1, max_row=1, min_col=1, max_col=itog_sheet.max_column, values_only=False):
            for cell in row:
                maxRow = itog_sheet.max_row
                if cell.value == FolderName:
                    SearchColumn = cell.column # находим нужный столбец по его номеру
                    print(itogName, itogLen)
                    for row in range(itog_sheet.max_column):
                        itog_sheet.cell(row = maxRow + 1, column=1, value=itogName)
                        itog_sheet.cell(row = maxRow + 1, column=SearchColumn, value=itogLen)
                itogWB.save(itogFileName)
                itogWB.close()

так вот, без сохранения и закрытия файла, т.е. без последних двух команд, код выполняет функцию, т.е. выводит на экран все значения, которые необходимо записать в файл.
но при сохранении, команда print(itoName) выводит только первое значение из списка и, соответственно, его и сохраняет в файле.
Полагаю, тут какая-то незначительная ошибка, но не могу ее найти.

Так у вас в этом коде нигде itogName не меняется, на экран будет выводиться одно и то же значение. Не понимаю, как при этом может быть то, что вы пишете: "выводит на экран все значения, которые необходимо записать в файл".  А что касается последних двух строк кода, то уберите у них один отступ.

значение itogName берется из словаря. Наверно надо было весь код выложить, но он большой.
Да на экран вывод делается правильно. И да, я пробовал изменить отступы, но это не помогло, что, собственно и поставило меня в тупик

При чём здесь другой код? Вот в этом данном коде у вас три (!!!) вложенных цикла, внутри которых печатается одно и то же значение, которое никак не меняется внутри этих трёх циклов. Выглядит это странно. Либо тут всё правильно и тогда этот print имеет смысл вынести до циклов, чтобы зря не печатать одно и то же, либо тут ошибка и это значение должно как-то меняться внутри циклов.

Вы что-то поменяли, а эта переменная по-прежнему нигде в коде не меняется. Ну да ладно. Попробуйте всё-таки у последних двух строк кода убрать один отступ/табуляцию. Может это то, что вам нужно.

Увы, это не сработало

Тогда нужно больше кода в вопросе, нужно больше рассказать об исходных данных и о том, что вы хотите получить. И ещё раз о приведённом куске кода в вопросе. Очень странно, что у вас три вложенных цикла, при этом значения, которые вы пишете в ячейки, нигде не меняются в этом коде. Переменная последнего цикла coll_index нигде не используется. Это всё говорит о том, что либо вы вообще не то что-то делаете, либо у вас избыточный код, который можно сократить (возможно, эти циклы вообще не нужны).

Я прошу прощения, поторопился и не тот и ни тем исправил.
представил более подробно. Получается, что ключ из словаря и количество значений необходимо добавить в таблицу. В таблице в начале только 2 столбца "Наименование отдела" и "Дата файла" (FolderName). Я делал так: если найдено значение: записываем номер столбца, а дальше запись идет в 1 столбец и в столбец с номером cell.column.
В дальнейшем, файлы должны будут записывать следующим столбцов и т.д.

Вот описал проблему и понял, что единственная проблема в данном случае сидит перед моим монитором.
Я забыл, что у меня в самом начале есть цикл и пытался его еще раз завести. в итоге, понял,
убрать все это безобразие и написать:
maxRow = itog_sheet.max_row
itog_sheet.cell(row = maxRow + 1, column=1, value=itogName)
itog_sheet.cell(row = maxRow + 1, column=2, value=itogLen)
itogWB.save(itogFileName)
itogWB.close()

для того, чтобы все заработало так, как необходимо!
Всем спасибо!
Может повеселил )

Грамотно написать вопрос - это половина пути к решению проблемы. Не редки случаи, что пока пытаешься сформулировать вопрос для кого-то другого, сам его решаешь )
